# ASP Elseif code not working correctly

Tags: asp-classic

I need assistance with asp code. My TYPEID 3 is not going to the correct link. It is defaulting to the last link. I'm trying to set the standard link for different TYPEID 's information from a database. All the other TYPEID's work with the exception of TYPE 3. Any help would be appreciated.

```vb
<%
set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSql = "SELECT * from product_types order by product_types.sortorder;"
objRS.Open strSql, objConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
If objRS.EOF then
    response.write "There is currently an error with the store.</p>"
Else
    y=0
    While not objRS.EOF
'           set objRSrandomimg = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
'           strSQLrandomimg = "SELECT products.*, product_pubtype.* FROM products INNER JOIN product_pubtype ON products.pubtype = product_pubtype.PUBTYPEID WHERE (product_pubtype.pubtypeimage = 1) AND (products.instock = 1) AND (products.type = " & objRS("TYPEID") & ")"
'           objRSrandomimg.Open strSQLrandomimg, objConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
'           rndMax = CInt(objRSrandomimg.RecordCount)
'           objRSrandomimg.MoveFirst
'           Randomize Timer
'           rndNumber = Int(RND * rndMax)
'           objRSrandomimg.Move rndNumber
        y=y+1
        If y mod 2 = 1 Then
            If objRS("TYPEID")=5 then
                    %>
  < tr>
    < td valign="bottom">
      < a href="/store/listitems2.asp?type=5&prodcat=22">
        <%=objRS("typename")%>
          < /a>
            </td>
            <%
            else
    %>
              < tr>
                < td valign="bottom">
                  < a href="/store/listitems.asp?type=<%=objRS(" TYPEID ")%>">
                    <%=objRS("typename")%>
                      < /a>
                        </td>
                        <%
            End If
        Else
            If objRS("TYPEID")=4 then

    %>
                          < tr>
                            < td valign="bottom">
                              < a href="/store/listitems2.asp?type=<%=objRS(" TYPEID ")%>&prodcat=21">
                                <%=objRS("typename")%>
                                  < /a>
                                    </td>
                                    <%

            elseif objRS("TYPEID")=3 then

    %>

                                      < tr>
                                        < td valign="bottom">
                                          < a href="/store/listitems2.asp?type=<%=objRS(" TYPEID ")%>&prodcat=17">
                                            <%=objRS("typename")%>
                                              < /a>
                                                </td>

                                                <%

            elseIf objRS("TYPEID")=2 then

    %>

                                                  < tr>
                                                    < td valign="bottom">
                                                      < a href="/store/listitems2.asp?type=<%=objRS(" TYPEID ")%>&prodcat=16">
                                                        <%=objRS("typename")%>
                                                          < /a>
                                                            </td>

                                                            <%

            else

    %>
                                                              < td valign="bottom">
                                                                < a href="/store/listitems.asp?type=<%=objRS(" TYPEID ")%>">
                                                                  <%=objRS("typename")%>
                                                                    < /a>
                                                                      </td>
                                                                      < /tr>
                                                                        <%
            End If
        End If
'           objRSrandomimg.Close
'           Set objRSrandomimg = Nothing
        objRS.movenext
    Wend
    If y mod 2 = 1 Then

%>
                                                                          < td> & nbsp;
                                                                            < /td>
                                                                              </tr>
                                                                              <%
    End If
%>
                                                                                < tr>
                                                                                  < td colspan="2">
                                                                                    < a href="/store/listitems.asp"> Show All
                                                                                      < /a>
                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                        < /tr>
                                                                                          < /table>
                                                                                            <%
End If
'   response.write randomstoreid()
%>
```

Comment: Looks like one of these is missing at the start - `<%`. If you format this so it takes up less room and people can see everything easily it might help get a response.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code with everything that was in the section.

Comment: If this is how you format code, I’d refuse to work on it. It’s a key skill to learn to structure your code so it is easily understandable to other  developers.

Answer (score 0):

If your are checking if y is even or odd, you should use

```
if y mod 2 = 0 Then
```

Use a function to put it more clear

```
If IsEven(y) Then
   ...
End if

Function IsEven(ByVal numberToCheck)
  If numberToCheck Mod 2 = 0 Then
    IsEven = True
  Else
    IsEven = False
  End if
End Function
```

After that, clean your code to search for problems

```
While not objRS.EOF
    y=y+1
    If IsEven(y) Then
        response.Write "Even and type=" + objRS("TYPEID") + "<br>"
        If objRS("TYPEID")=5 then
        else
        End If
    Else
        response.Write "Odd and type=" + objRS("TYPEID") + "<br>"
        If objRS("TYPEID")=4 then

        elseif objRS("TYPEID")=3 then
           response.Write "Success!<br>"
        elseIf objRS("TYPEID")=2 then

        else

        End If
    End If
    objRS.movenext
Wend
```